# Is my anger justified?

Tags: work-life-balance, overtime

First, some background. I live and work in the US and have 18 years experience in my engineering career across a variety of industries. All of my experience has been focused on product development, but I have only been with my latest employer for about 7 months.

So, on to the issue at hand...my boss recently sent out a notice to the engineers in the department, that we're now expected to work 6 Saturdays/year  as "manufacturing floor support". This is in addition to the normal workweek and those weekends we work at our discretion to support our ongoing projects. When I asked what exactly we're supposed to do as "manufacturing floor support", I was told that the "manufacturing (hourly) guys are complaining because they have to work weekends and the engineers don't so it's time to share the pain". That neglects the fact that they get overtime pay and since we're salaried, our paychecks stay the same.

Personally, this really makes me angry. I work hard, I work smart and I get things done and I feel like this is a kick in the teeth. I place a very high value on my weekend time, especially the weekends I have with my kids. I can't leave them alone at home and I can't bring them to work. We're not getting any extra pay, no additional time off, nothing. I feel like this is simply a bridge too far and I should start networking, looking for a new employer.

Am I justified in being this angry about this, or am I making a mountain out of a molehill?

Is adding mandatory weekend work a common practice in other fields?

Comment: This is going to be _very_ opinion based.  It will very likely be closed as off-topic for being either primarily opinion based or not an answerable question because there is no clear answer.

Comment: The real question that you should ask: Can a salaried employee be asked to work on Saturdays with a reason like this, and how can I tell my boss that this is a bad idea?

Comment: @ Jane-S You're right. Let me try to rephrase things. What I'm really after is understanding if this kind of this is a common practice in other fields...

Comment: @DLS3141 - No, this is not common practice. This is the stupidest thing I have heard of so far.  Clear out your desk.  Don't have any personal items at all at work.  Something tells me you're going to be leaving with 2 minutes' notice, and you'll probably have company.

Comment: Don't get angry. Get interviewing.

Comment: What you are describing doesn't make sense.  Are you sure that the problem isn't "the hourly guys working on the weekend get frustrated when something goes wrong and they have to sit on their hands waiting for someone to locate an IT person that may or may not be able to fix the problem or pass the buck to someone else"?  That could certainly motivate management to start some sort of on call process and would be a solvable problem.  Telling people to show up to be miserable because other people are miserable is just daft.

Comment: @ Justin-Cave It's not an IT engineering position. I'm a mechanical engineer.

Comment: Even so... Having at least part of tbe engineering staff on call on weekends to put out fires makes sense. Having enginedring do some rotational time in or observing manufacturing to look for ways to improve design or practices makes sense. Asking salaried employees to work overtime when there's a crash priority may be justified, with that overload made up for in bonus or flextime or similar. If your description is accurate, however, this sounds like a company in trouble.

Comment: Does it matter if we think your anger at the situation is justified or not? I don't think that's really the issue, is it?

Comment: @keshlam It would be one thing if there were some kind of compensation or reward for working a mandatory 6 day week instead of a 5 day week. And yes, we do work longer hours and the occasional weekend to keep a project from going off the rails, but this is different.

Comment: It happened to me once, we had to work X number of hours every weekend because our government contract got paid for overtime even though the employees did not. When they started enforcing this was when I started looking for another job.

Comment: @keshlam An engineer on call to put out a fire is not the same as on the floor.  If they just want floor experience they could schedule that during regular work hours.

Answer (score 6):

I don't even come close to believing these hourly people are complaining about time and a half on weekends.

This is a (weakly veiled) cost cutting measure period.

The opposite.  Hourly manufacturing is going to complain about loss of hours and overtime.

Mandatory "covering" for hourly is not common.  If hourly was union this would not happen.  This is not a good policy.  It will piss off both hourly and salary employees.

You did not get degree in engineering to work the floor on weekends.  To me this is like asking you to stay after and mop floors for free.  I worked as a engineer at an plant and if union went out on strike yes we covered.  But we got 3x pay to cover.

Comment: I didn't read it as salaried folks taking over for hourly folks on the weekend. I read it as "if we have to be here on Saturday, they should be here too." Which, IMHO, is even worse.

Comment: @alroc If it is "share time" that is even worse!  If management is doing this to appease and not a cost cutting measure then OUCH.  For sure I would look for another job.

Answer (score 2):

It is stupid, and it is in no way justified. The work that you are supposed to do is not part of your salaried work. There is no business reason why you should be there on these saturdays. You are perfectly justified to be angry. You are also perfectly justified to refuse, since this is definitely not something that anyone can request you to do as a salaried employee.

You should look for a new job immediately. As always the advice: Don't quit the old job until you have signed for a new job. I would assume that you are not the only one wanting to leave under these conditions.